# docker-compose variable format

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file.  I have created the .env file as well with the relevant variables.  when I attempt to run docker-compose using this file it complains about the variables.  I know in Ansible yaml I declare the vars inside the file and can call them anywhere.  Not sure what what I am doing wrong.

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  ${hostname01}:
    image:  apline:3.12
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: ${hostname01}
    environment:
    volumes:
      - ${hostname01}_Data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    
services:
  ${hostname02}:
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${mySQLRootPass}
    volumes:
      - ${hostname02}_Data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
volumes:
  ${hostname01}_Data:
  ${hostname02}_Data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: You cannot substitute key names with environment variables in the compose file, only values. Moreover, you are defining `services` twice which will end up with only the last definition being used.

Comment: Compose also has the notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) that gets included in the generated names of containers, networks, and volumes; it's okay to hard-code `mariadb` for `hostname02`, for example, and Compose will name the volume `dirname_mariadb_Data` (where `dirname` is the name of the containing directory) so as to not conflict with other similar Compose-based projects.